# Query Dinamica Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Necessito de criar uma query dinamica, em que a váriaveL `DayOfWeek.Monday` é dinâmica, como o posso definir?

```
DataClassesPDataContext pe = new DataClassesPDataContext();
            var qry = from p in pe.R
                      join q in pe.V on p.V equals q.V_
                      where p.Data < data 
                      where q.I == `v`
                      where p.Data.DayOfWeek == `DayOfWeek.Monday`
                      select(p.Q);

            return qry.ToList().Average();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde que a variável `DayOfWeek.Monday` seja do mesmo tipo da coluna `DayofWeek` funcionará conforme:

```
DataClassesPDataContext pe = new DataClassesPDataContext();
            var qry = from p in pe.R
                      join q in pe.V on p.V equals q.V_
                      where p.Data < data 
                      where q.I == `v`
                      where p.Data.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                      select(p.Q);

            return qry.ToList().Average();
```